# How to search shipping address in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want search shipping address by customer name, company, city or postcode. Please help me

This my code, but it get double, it gte shipping and billing address, i want get only shipping address.

```
$addressCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
$addressCollection->getSelect()->where("lastname like '%$customerName%' and company like '%$customerCompany%' and city like '%$customerCity%' and postcode like '%$customerCode%'");
var_dump($addressCollection->getData());exit;
```

UPDATE

I follow answer and it show error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lastname like '%Nhân%' and company like '%%' and city like '%%' and postcode li' at line 1, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_address` AS `main_table` WHERE (address_type = 'shipping' lastname like '%Nhân%' and company like '%%' and city like '%%' and postcode like '%%')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to just add "address_type" condition into your above code like this one.

```
$addressCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('address_type','shipping');
$addressCollection->getSelect()->where("lastname like '%$customerName%' and company like '%$customerCompany%' and city like '%$customerCity%' and postcode like '%$customerCode%'");
var_dump($addressCollection->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: it show error, please check update question

Comment: I update the answer Kindly check.

Comment: Thank you, can u help me a proplem? how to get only shipping address in storeId = 1 ?

Comment: you want list by store specific?

Comment: yes, i want like this

Answer (score 2):

```
$customerName = "Nhân";
$customerCity = "";
$customerCompany = "";
$customerCode = "";

$addressCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->getCollection();
$addressCollection->getSelect()->where("lastname like '%$customerName%' and company like '%$customerCompany%' and city like '%$customerCity%' and postcode like '%$customerCode%' and address_type= 'shipping' ");

//echo "SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order_address` AS `main_table` WHERE (lastname like '%Nhân%' and company like '%%' and city like '%%' and postcode like '%%' and address_type= 'shipping' )";

echo $addressCollection->getSelect();
var_dump($addressCollection->getData());exit;
```